# Embedding a cs-cart website in an iFrame

Tags: php, html, iframe, cs-cart

I am developing a cs-cart website for a customer, who wants to allow embedding of a "neutral" version of the site into other website.
I have developed a second store, with neutral skin (white, no logos...)
But when I try to embed it into an iframe on another site, nothing is shown. Other sites work.
I undestrad this has to to with "same domain policy"
What can be blocking my cs-cart website to ne shown in another site?
What can be done to circumvent this?

Comment: What does the browser's developer console say when you try to load the page?

Comment: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://whitelabel.xxxxxxxxx.it/australia-it/sydney-it/ does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: So stop telling your server to output that header.

Comment: I am on IIS...I have checked in Site Administration-->HttpResponseHeaders, and there's nothing...

Other website on the same webserver allow framing....

Comment: Then possibly the header is being output by the PHP. Find that and turn it off.

Comment: yes, that's a possiblity I am investigating. I have to inspect php code in CS-cart, version 3...could be that php code is outputting the header and not th server...

Answer (score 0):

Your server is [configured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to tell browsers not to show the page in an iframe belonging to another site.

There is no way to work around that. Reconfigure the server so it doesn't output that [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Answer (score 0):

found it:

i was in the prepare.php file in root path
around line 86:

```
// Click-jacking protection
header("X-Frame-Options: sameorigin");
```

simply commented the option and then it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

After searching i didn't find direct answer searching at cs cart directlry found

> that /var/www/html/app/schemas/security/http_content_policy.php

Adding * to 'allow' like below worked for me

```
'frame-ancestors' => [
        'self' => true,
        'allow' => ['*']
    ],
```