# Cs-cart pages in an iframe. No Popups?

Tags: html, css, iframe, cs-cart

I have enclosed a CS-Cart page in an iFrame on an External webpage

(see for example this: http://www.sagreinitalia.it/temp/citycards.html)

Navigation is OK, but if I try to Add to Cart (see button "Aggiungi al carrello") 
the popup doesn't work.

I have set sandbox options as follows

```
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
```

but no way to accomplish my expected behaviour... Any hints?

Comment: Your example link goes nowhere.

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555711/embedding-a-cs-cart-website-in-an-iframe


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555711/embedding-a-cs-cart-website-in-an-iframe